# jQueryUI Accordion with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I'm trying to build an accordion with several "sub-forms" in it. Upon moving to the next panel, I want to submit the form fields in the oldPanel. There can be up to nine accordion sections, and therefore up to nine separate html forms with a metric buttload of input fields in each form.

When I click from header 1 to header 2 the very first time, it works (as scripted anyways - still having trouble getting the form's content to serialize). When I click from header 2 back to 1, form becomes an empty object. How can I submit the form in each respective panel upon the closure of that panel?

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  $("#accordionSubmit").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        var tbl = $('#accordionSubmit').data('table');
        var form = $(ui.oldPanel).find('form'); //.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: form,
            success: function (data) {
                $(ui.newPanel).html(data);
                console.log(form);

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert("Nope");
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="accordionSubmit" class="accordionSubmit" data-table="jto-submit">
    <h3>Header Name 1</h3>

<div>
    <form name="form" id="a">
        <input type="hidden" id="stuff" value="YAY">
        <input type="hidden">
    </form>Contents</div>
    <h3>Header Name 2</h3>

<div>
    <form name="form" id="b">
        <input type="hidden" id="stuff1" value="YAY1">
        <input type="hidden">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track.  When a new panel is activated, you receive an event containing the identity of the old and new panels.  Given that you now know the panel that is being closed, you can submit the form contained within it.  I think I'm missing your core puzzle?

Comment: My problem is that after the first change of panels, I stop getting the identity of the old panels regardless of how many subsequent changes between panels that I make. I'm not sure why I'm losing the value of the closed panel and I'm not sure how to submit the form data for each individual form, not knowing (from the JS perspective) which forms will be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should put `name` attributes on your form fields. Serialization uses the field's `name` not `id`.

Then you can serialize the form using the `serializeArray()` function like this:

```
var form = $(ui.oldPanel).find('form').serializeArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the name attribute piece. However, I am still losing the value after the first firing of the beforeActivate.

Comment: Check this Plunk, seems to be working fine to me: http://plnkr.co/edit/uJkiZN?p=preview

Comment: You're right! And I found what was screwing up the object: `$(ui.newPanel).html(data);` must've been overwriting the object causing it to come back blank. As soon as I removed that from the ajax script it worked. Thanks!